# Yearly interest rate to monthly - smooth forecasting in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

trying to run a smooth monthly forecast for multiple years for changing interest rates with yearly interest rate input.

In other words, I have interest rate for 2022 (10%), 2023 (15%), 2024 (12%) but I want to forecast on a monthly basis smoothly, instead of having 0.8% (=POWER((1+0.1),(1/12))-1) for January '22 - December '22 and then change to 1.17% for January '23... I would like to smooth the values to account for changing value (something like 0.8% Jan '22, 0.85% Feb '22 etc...

Is there a maths guru that can help out with making this a smooth monthly forecast?

Thanks!

Mikeee

Comment: What are your smoothing assumptions? I guess if you figure that out, then you won't need to ask us. I do think that you using a compounding that it would be very difficult, and you will lose information. If you just want one percentage over your whole term, do your calculation, then back into it with the `'=RATE()` formula

Comment: Why do you want to "smooth" it?  **In addition to** what @gns100 writes, what kind of interest (real, nominal, effective, annual) is represented by those annual numbers?

Answer (score 0):

So, you want the interest in January to be some (correct for this) amount and then February rises by some amount and twice that for March and so on until 11 times that for December so the interest rose smoothly by that extra amount per month and still totaled the year's correct total interest. Maybe the interest for January is $4.50 and rises a dollar a month until December it's $15.50.

Of course, that assumes the interest rate compounds annually, not monthly or daily. Slightly more complex if not yearly. (This is called "simple interest" by the way and with computers available to do all the calculations, it is going away, pretty much.)

Anyway, how do you suppose that'd work out as a math problem? Well, you'd have "x" amount in January, then "x+$1" in February, and so on. Add those up over the year and you have the 12 monthly x's plus 1+2+3+...+9+10+11 = 66. So 12x + 66 and it would equal whatever the yearly interest is. Say $120. Do the algebra and you get x = $4.50. So monthly, you'd have $4.50, $5.50, $6.50...$13.50, $14.50, $15.50.

But that isn't "perfect", is it? I mean, that $4.50, why it? Why not $2.00 with a bigger bump each month? Ideally, it ought to be $0 of beginning interest and all "bump" — but just putting $0 in for x, one gets no interest in January. So say January has some mythical "bump" amount, then February twice that, up to December being 12 times that. Then it'd be smooth, with the starting amount equalling the amount each month rises. PERFECTLY smooth then!

So, do some arithmetic again, but now 1+2+3+...+10+11+12 (12 values, not the 11 from above). It equals 78. So there are 78 "bumps" to distribute, one in January, two in February, and so on until 12 in December. Ahh, so obvious now, eh?

In the $120 example, that'd be $120/78 = $20/13 = about $1.54 each "bump."

All you need to do then is substitute the year's total interest in that division. If it's $10,000 at 10% simple interest for the year, that'd be $1,000 of interest to distribute like this:  $1,000/78 = about $12.82 per month. So the year 2022 would be $12.82 for January, $25.64 for February, $38.46 for March and so on. Starting at $12.82 and rising by $12.82 each month. Pretty much the definition of "smooth." There'd be 4¢ extra to slip in, but a penny here and there every three months is easy and not really mattering to the smoothness.

The "78" is the same for every year, so just collect the principal amount for the year, the simple interest rate for the year, multiply them, and divide by 78. Since this is Excel, you can simply multiply that calculation by the "month number" for the month.

For example, say Column A has the year's principal (calculated or hand entered however you find appropriate), Column B has the interest rate (like principal, however you choose to make it appear there), and columns C through N have the months and each row is a new year. You either have headings for each month's column that are actual dates, like 1/1/"year" and formatted as, say, "mmm" so they show as "Jan", "Feb" and so on so you oculd use `=MONTH(C1)` and it would return a 1 which you'd use as that column's multiplier, OR you could have text headings that you convert in a formula any of ten ways into a date and use `MONTH()` on it. Either way, or a different one, you get multipliers of 1-12. So each cell under the months would have something like:

```
=((Principal * Interest Rate) / 78) * MONTH(Heading)
```

Since the principal and interest rate are in A1 and B1 and "Heading" would be C1 through N1, it'd look more particularly like:

```
=((A1 * B1) / 78) * Month(N1)
```

for cell C2, then copy and paste it into all twelve months and each row you use. Just that, written once, then pasted once.

If you have `Spill` functionality, you can just write one formula and it will Spill into all the cells needed:  (say you have three years, so rows, 2, 3, and 4 are used)

```
=((A2:A4 * B2:B4) / 78) * SEQUENCE(1,12)
```

since, if you have `Spill`, you also have the `SEQUENCE()` function and you know you are using all the months, so generating a sequence of 1-12 is just as good as the "slick" `MONTH()` thing with the headings. Write it, press Enter, and all 36 of the cells will fill in.

Toss in a `ROUND()` to help catch the extra, or fewer, cents, and make the last cell (December) actually subtract the sum the other 11 cells in the row from the interest you calculate and the interest will all add up. Don't get tricker... it would only make things closer to "right" and "right" right down to the cent isn't the goal:  the goal is smoothness so rounding the final result for each month is more on point than the "right" way.

Long answer, sounds so much worse than it is. It's just that formula above, or the one you have to paste into all the required cells. Adjust for the columns you really use, and the location of the year's principal and interest rate, and you're done.